Queueing model with two arrival rates
Suppose I have a process that has poisson arrival rate for some fixed time span $T$ and zero arrival rate for the next time span $T$ alternatively while being processed throughout with service times exponentially distributed. Does there exist closed form expression for waiting time in queue and length of queue for such a model. This seems to be a very common problem for factories but I couldn’t find such a model analysed in literature. Can anyone point me to a resource?
